# How to get the navbar to the bottom?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm new to the CSS and so confused about it! Please tell me what am I doing wrong here and teach me what I should know!

here is the preview-

[image]

This is the html and css code-

**index.html-**

```
<section class="section-1">
        <img class="logo" src="./Assets/Asset 2@3x.png" width="320" alt="Brand Icon">
        <p class="description">Luxury Jewelry Store</p>
    
    <nav class="navbar">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-link">Home</a>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-link">My Cart</a>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-link">My Orders</a>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-link">FAQs</a>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-link">About Us</a>
        <div class="search">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass searchIcon"></i>
                <input class="searchBox" placeholder="Search..." type="search">
                <input type="submit" value="Search" class="searchButton">
                
        </div>
    </nav>
    </section>
```

**styles.css-**

```
.section-1{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.navbar{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #92A9BD;
}
```

I am trying to get the navbar to the bottom of the page. I think I'm getting confused in flex. I tried adding

```
justify-self:center;
```

but then I found out that it doesn't work in flex. So what I should do now in this case?

And also how can I make navbar stick to the top when I scroll down?

Answer (score 1):

You can fix your problem by using `position: absolute`.

First, you give the relative position to the section tag so that the navbar is positioned based on it.
Then you give `position: absolute` and `bottom: 0` to navbar.

like this:

```
.section-1{
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.navbar{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #92A9BD;
}
```

If you want, you can achieve this result by using display: flex.
You should do this:

CSS:

```
.section-1 {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.navbar {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #92A9BD;
}
```

HTML:

```
<section class="section-1">
    <div>
        <img class="logo" src="./Assets/Asset 2@3x.png" width="320" alt="Brand Icon">
        <p class="description">Luxury Jewelry Store</p>
    </div>

    <nav class="navbar">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-link">Home</a>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-link">My Cart</a>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-link">My Orders</a>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-link">FAQs</a>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-link">About Us</a>
        <div class="search">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass searchIcon"></i>
                <input class="searchBox" placeholder="Search..." type="search">
                <input type="submit" value="Search" class="searchButton">
                
        </div>
    </nav>
    </section>
```

But the point is that the first DIV sticks to the top of the page.

Comment: Thank You, it worked, but can you give me an explanation for this answer please, like why we are giving them position relative to section and absolute to the navbar and why bottom property wasn't working without these properties? Thank You!

Comment: In this situation, you can not give `position: relative` to the `section` tag and it will still work, but when you add an element outside the `section` tag, the positions will be broken.